# asp + msaccess , compare keywords in a table

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

Hopefully someone has done this so has a bit of code which may help me

I currently have this query

```
ForumID = request("ID") 
QID = ForumID

DB.CreateQueryDef QID, "SELECT * FROM Topic WHERE Keywords = '" & QID & "' ORDER BY LastPost DESC"
```

What I have is a table topic which contains the topics. I have added a field keywords, which will have keywords eg "motocross, mx, motox"

How can i query the database eg any table which contains the keyword motocross?

Also how can this use multiple words

```
eg
two topics
topic1 -> Keywords motocross, mx
topic2 -> Keywords motocross, dance
```

if eg search.asp?ID= motocross unrelated

it will search database for both, eg get all topics where keywords field contain eith of the 2 words in query, or 4 words or more

Also is it possible to do relavent search like youtubes like this?

two topics
topic1 -> Keywords motocross, 1
topic2 -> Keywords motocross, 2

eg search.asp?ID=motocross 1

topic 1 will show first as both words in query match "motocross" and "1" whereas topic2 only has motocross

is it possible to do this so it will count keyword matches

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your querystring should not contain spaces. Use a different delimiter. A + is a good one to use. So your URL will look like: search.asp?ID=motocross+1 instead.

This will split your kewwords into an array, then take them one at a time to build the and clause. The replace removes the first AND.

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Topic WHERE"
ForumID = request("ID")
QID = Split(ForumID, "+")
For Each KW in QID
    SQL = SQL & "AND Keywords Like '*" & QID & "*' "
Next
SQL = Replace(SQl, "WHEREAND", "WHERE")
SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY LastPost DESC"
```

Comment: How would the database query look for this? 

I have this atm which isnt working but it sais mismatch on like 
   `"SQL = SQL & "AND Keywords" line`

   `SQL = "SELECT * FROM Topic WHERE"
    ForumID = request("ID")
QID = Split(ForumID, "+")
For Each KW in QID
    SQL = SQL & "AND Keywords = '" & QID & "' "
Next
SQL = Replace(SQL, "WHEREAND", "WHERE")
SQL = SQL & " ORDER BY LastPost DESC"

'create the querydef
DB.CreateQueryDef QID, SQL`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using LIKE ??

"select * from table where field LIKE '%" & value & "%'"

Comment: Hey, I have been trying for hours and hours on the like statement, ive tried nearly all combinations i can find / think of where none work

Comment: I have a simple search working with that, if the search phrase is "houses in uruguay"  the script splits by words and I made the sql like this:

"select * from TABLEwhere FIELD like '%casas%' and FIELD like '%en%' and FIELD like '%uruguay%' "

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your Query with "OR" ....

I have 2 keyword(car , Bus) so my query will be like

DB.CreateQueryDef QID, "SELECT * FROM Topic WHERE (Keywords = 'car' OR Keywords = 'Bus') ORDER BY LastPost DESC"

this is just example as static query you can make it run time with loop of your comma separated values..